What is the maximal open set $D \subset C$, such that $f : D \to \mathbb{C}$, $f(z) := Log(z^5+1)$, is well defined and analytic
I want to solve this exercise

What is the maximal open set $D \subset C$, such that $f : D \to \mathbb{C}$, $f(z) := Log(z^5+1)$, is well defined and analytic?

The first thing is that I drew the five roots of the whole negative line $(-\infty,0)$

Then I removed every $z$ on these five lines  where $|z|\le 1$

My answer is the whole plane except these five lines but I am not sure about this.

Like with the plain logarithm, or the square root, there is no "the" maximal open set. There are plenty to choose from, although some are definitely easier to descrobe than others.

Any simply connected domain which does not contain the roots of $z^5+1$ will do.

@MartinR So is my answer correct ?
